# Springsource tool suite and Spring template project

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, springsource

I'm trying to set up a new Spring MVC project using springsource tool suite and the Spring Template project wizard.

The wizard asks for a top-level package name such as com.mytravel.company, but it seems to ignore any top level package greater than 3 levels deep

Is this by design, or is it a bug in the wizard.

Can anybody recommend another wizard to generate the shell of a spring mvc project.

Thanks

Comment: I posted this on the spring forum, but I've been waiting for the moderators to post it up.

Comment: Almost a year later, someone reported this to the Spring JIRA, and it should be fixed in 2.8.0.M1: https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-1964

Answer (score 0):

> The wizard asks for a top-level package name such as com.mytravel.company, but it seems to ignore any top level package greater than 3 levels deep

I can't confirm this behavior (didn't check myself) but a dummy workaround would be to use a package name that gets accepted and to modify it after the facts. This doesn't seem to be a blocking issue.

Comment: Not a blocking issue, but just annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but a confirmation.  More than a year after this question the latest version of STS still limits the package to three levels.  A VERY annoying limitation!